# PHP considera que null es igual a cero

Tags: php

tengo esta duda en cuanto a un if que estoy haciendo en php, lo que pasa es que recibo una variable POST pero esta al no tener aun nada es considerada como NULL, pero eso a php le resulta ser 0 ya que en mi if estoy condicionando la $varaible <= 0 solo que esta es null.

```
$CantidadInicial = $_POST["cantidad_inicial"];


if($CantidadInicial <= 0){
   var_dump($CantidadInicial);
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
   echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal.fire("La cantidad de la caja no puede ser 0!","preuba con cotra cantidad !","");';
   echo '}, 500);</script>';
   }
```

en mi `var_dump($CantidadInicial);` me arroja el valor es NULL solo que no deberia cumplirse la condición

Comment: En esta respuesta lo explican bastante bien: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624188/10382744

Comment: i por que no evaluas que el indice exista antes de utilizarlo???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que estas implementando php en un formulario web.
lo primero que suelo validar es que en la variable `$_POST` exista y contenga el indice a tratar, esa validacion la hago de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
try
{
    if(!isset($_POST['campo'])){
        // si no existe no tiene sentido continuar con la ejecucion.
        throw new Exception('no se recibió el dato "campo" que es obligatorio para el calculo');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    
}
```

***output:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas esto tambien te sirve para capturar y validar cualquier otro error en los escenarios de prueba y desarrollo que manejes, conexiones a base de datos; a FTP Etc...

---

Tambien es importante que comprendas por que estas recibiendo un falso/positivo
eso se debe al casteo de datos para la verificacion:

php casteara los valores a tipos lo mas posible cercanos antes de emitir un warning o fatal error.

te detallo la siguiente informacion que se encuentra en el sitio en ingles: [Liga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624047/null-with-php-and-operators/5624188#5624188)

> http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
>
> El nulo se convierte en falso y el -1 se convierte en verdadero, falso
> es menos que verdadero
>
> En sus primeros dos ejemplos, nulo se convierte en falso y 0 se
> convierte en falso, falso no es menor ni mayor que falso, pero es
> igual a él.

en tu caso el null sera casteado a falso y el 0 sera casteado a falso; por lo tanto se cumple la parte de falso es igual a falso.

Comment: ya comprendo, gracias por la aclaración